# How to select a css class with jquery from an external stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to select a button every time I press it, it changes to a different style of my css, the problem is that this code is made for online css code, if I want to take it for example from the `css/stilos.css` folder and make jquery find the class from there as it should? this can?

```
const switchButton = $("button#switch");
 
$('button').click(switchButton, function(e) {

    document.body.classList.toggle('dark'); //toggle the HTML body the class 'dark'
    switchButton.classList.toggle('active');//toggle the HTML button with the id='switch' with the class 'active'
});
```

I also attach the html code

```
<button class="darkModeSwitch" id="switch">
      <span><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></span>   
      <span><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></span>
```

I would like to know if these lines:

```
document.body.classList.toggle('dark'); //toggle the HTML body the class 'dark'

switchButton.classList.toggle('active');//toggle the HTML button with the id='switch' with the class 'active'
```

is there a way to call them in another way that I don't know to access this external css file and get these classes.

Comment: Link that `css` file in your `html`

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee The css path would be something like `css/stilos.css` the classes that it takes are dark and active that are defined in this css, it is not necessary to add them I think since the effect they do as such is not the reason for the question but, the jquery and how you can access these classes.